# A surjective map $S^{2} \longrightarrow S^{2}$

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, differential-topology

Is there any continuous surjective map  $S^{2} \longrightarrow S^{2}$ such that it sends one of the meridians of the first sphere into the south pole of the second one?

I can see that is true, but I'm having a hard time figuring out a proper "analytical" definition (with some kind of coordinates etc.).

EDIT: For a meridian I mean the shortest arc from the north pole to the south pole (with poles included).

Comment: What does 'into the south pole' mean? Do you want the meridian to be mapped to a single point? (It actually doesn't matter which one, since we can change that by a simple rotation at will.)

Comment: @Stefan Exactly, I was just trying to be as "visual" as possible. Nevertheless, I made a mistake, since I found that a meridian on a sphere is defined as a circle passing trough the two poles (north and south) and a third given point on the sphere. Therefore I had to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will prove that the following map meets the requirements:

> $$\cases{X=2xy\\Y=-2yz\\Z=2y^2-1}\qquad\text{if $y>0$}$$  and
>   $$\cases{X=0\\Y=0\\Z=-1}\qquad\text{otherwise}$$

In spherical coordinates (with the usual convention $0\leq \theta\leq\pi$ and $0\leq\phi\leq 2\pi$): $$f:(\theta,\phi)\mapsto \cases{(2\theta,\phi)& if $\theta\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$\\(\pi,0) & otherwise}$$
sends the *equator* to the south pole.

If you want to send a *meridian* to the SP, all you need is to send it first to the equator, and then apply the above map.

In Cartesian coordinates, the rotation represented by the following matrix sends the meridian of equation $\cases{y=0\\x^2+z^2=1}$ to the equator $\cases{z=0\\x^2+y^2=1}$:
$$M=\left(\matrix{1&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0}\right)$$

Now

- Start with Cartesian $\left(\matrix{x&y&z}\right)$.
- Apply $M$ to get $\left(\matrix{x&-z&y}\right)$.
- Turn to spherical: $$\theta =
     \arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}}{y}\right),
    \varphi = \arctan\left(\frac{-z}{x}\right)$$ (note that this change of variables formula is compatible with the
  convention $0\leq\theta\leq \pi$ on the northern hemisphere only, but
  this is sufficient for our purposes)
- Apply the map $f$ to get $$\theta =\cases{ 2\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}}{y}\right) & if $y>0$\\ 
    \pi&otherwise}$$
- Turn back to Cartesian $$\cases{X=\sin\left(2\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}}{y}\right)\right)\cdot\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{-z}{x}\right)\right)\\Y=\sin\left(2\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}}{y}\right)\right)\cdot\sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{-z}{x}\right)\right)\\Z=\cos\left(2\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}}{y}\right)\right)}\qquad\text{if $y>0$}$$
- Apply $\sin 2t=2\sin t\cos t$ to get the announced formula.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that this map sends a whole meridian to the south pole. For example, the north pole is fixed by this map, isn't it?

Comment: @ImreMezo I see. I read great circle instead of meridian. Anyway, it's easy to get around it, I will edit in a minute.

Comment: I tried to work it out by myself in an answer below, if you mind to check. Anyway, thank you for your time!

Comment: Actually, the map I defined below still doesn't work for my purposes... (I'm looking for a continuous surjective map $S^{2} \to S^{2}$ which sends a meridian to a single point, but being injective outside the meridian itself)

Comment: @ImreMezo There is no such map.

Comment: Thinking about it more, indeed such a map couldn't be continuous

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a map that maybe works.

Let $S^{2} \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be the unit sphere in the space, with center $(0,0,0)$. I put on this the following coordinates:

$t \in [-1,1]$ indicates a point on the line from $(-1,0,0)$ to $(1,0,0)$. If I fix a $t$ of this set, I consider the circle with center $(t,0,0)$, parallel to the $yz$ plane and with radius $1-|t|$. Now, I take $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ as the angle with the line passing trough the center and parallel to the $z$ axis in the $xz$ plane (such that the point $(0,0,-1)$ would have coordinates $(t,\theta)=(0,0)$, the point $(0,0,1)$ would have $(t,\theta)=(0,\pi)$ and so on.).

Now, the map I was looking for could be

$$f:(t,\theta)\mapsto \cases{(t,2\theta)& if $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$\\(t,2\pi) & if $\pi \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.}$$